# Closure and density of subspaces

Tags: real-analysis

Let $l^{\infty}$ be the space of bounded real sequences with the usual sup-norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$. This space has the following two subspaces: \begin{align} l_{0} & = \{(x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l^{\infty} : x_{n} = 0,\: \text{for sufficiently large n}\} \\ c_{0} & = \{(x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l^{\infty} : x_{n} \rightarrow 0 \}\end{align}

I'm supposed to show that the closure of $l_{0}$ in $l^{\infty}$ is $c_{0}$.

I have showed that $c_{0}$ is closed, but I can't show that $l_{0}$ is dense in $c_{0}$. I tried to show that if $(x_{m}^{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is in $c_{0}$ then $\|(x_{m}^{k})_{k}-(y_{m}^{k})_{k}\|_{\infty} < \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ and $(y_{m}^{k})_{k} \in l_{0}$. That is, I can find a sequence in $l_{0}$ such that the maximum distance between that sequnce and a sequence in $c_{0}$ is arbitrarily small.

Answer (score 0):

To show that the closure of $l_0$ is $c_0$, it remains to show that for every $x\in c_0$ there exists a sequence $(y_n)\in l_0$ such that $lim_ny_n=x$.
Write $x=(x^m)$, since $x\in c_0$, for every integer $n>0$ there exists $m_0$ such that for every $m>m_0$, $\|x^m\|<1/n$, define $y_{n}\in l_0$ by $y_{n}^l=x^l, l\leq m_0, y_{n}^l =0, l>m_0$. The limit of the sequence $(y_n)$ is $x$.